# Detect touch on rectangle that are using drawRect()

Tags: java, android, canvas, paint, rectangles

I am refering to this [tutorial](http://knowandroidmore.blogspot.sg/2013/05/resizable-rectangle-overlay-on-touch.html) to make a resizable rectangle. But in my case, I need more than that.

I need to drag and move the rectangle as well without touching on the point. Is this possible?
Which part of the code should I change?

Or is there any way to detect the rectangle that is drawn by using drawRect()?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the x and y coordinates of the click event and detect if this position is in the rectangle.

```
yourView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                int x = event.getX();
                int y = event.getY();
                if(x > rectLeftX && x < rectRightX && y > rectBottomY && y < rectTopY){
                    /* Trigger your action here */
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```